PyInstaller can't find docx module
I have a python program I wrote to parse through student data from powerschool and automatically generate a letter with their missing assignments to send to their parents. This program works great, but I am running into a problem trying to export it to an executable for my coworkers to use. WHenever I run PyInstaller, the resulting exe fails with the following error:
'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'

This is the same issue found in this stackoverflow post, but I have been unable to get the solution to work for me. As directed in the linked post, I created the .spec file below, but I still get the same error as before.
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from os import path
site_packages = next(p for p in sys.path if 'site-packages' in p)
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ['gradeReport2.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('logo.png', 'resources'), (path.join(site_packages,"docx","templates"), "docx/templates")],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='gradeReport2',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)


When I run pyinstaller with the spec file, I get the following error, which I am not sure how to address. When I navigate to the ...\site-packages folder, I can see that docx is not there, but I don't know why that is or where it would be instead.
Unable to find 'C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\docx\\templates' when adding binary and data files.

